# git branch is not showing all the branches

Tags: git

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/drupal-8.4.0$ git branch
```

I have installed drupal in my system ,I want to switch to other branch but when used git branch is not showing other branches !

Comment: if you mean remote branches then you should use git branch -a

Comment: @Pavel I tried but its not working , it does not return anything !

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Execute `git branch -av` to show all remote and local branches.

Answer (score 71):

It might be a possibility that you don't have those branches locally.

to pull all additional branches,

```
git fetch
```

it should be like this not like above

```
git fetch --all or git fetch <branch Name>
```

then you can use either `checkout` or `branch` to check if it shows

```
git checkout name-of-the-branch
git branch
```

Answer (score 11):

**git branch --all**

This git command will display all the branches.

Answer (score 11):

This can happen if your repo has 0 commits.  If you make a commit, your current branch will appear when you do: `git branch`.

Comment: omg :face-palm:

Answer (score 9):

Use `git branch -a` to see all branches in repo and then you can use `git checkout branchname` to checkout to respective branch

Comment: The error posted above to fetch from remote shows you have permission issue in ur local repo. You may need to change the directory permission to make it work. ,`chown -R youruser reponame` from your parent directory which contains your repo. If you used sudo to clone repo permission issue may happen

Comment: Use "git fetch"

Answer (score 8):

- Open git bash
- Run the following command in the right git project folder:

  ```
  git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
  ```
- Fetch

Then you should be finally able to see the other branches.

Comment: I actually face "fatal: invalid refspec '+refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/'" error. Is there other step I should do?

Comment: Broke repository with this command

Comment: The above commad is worng .This should be it

git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"

Answer (score 6):

Do a git fetch first in order to pull aditional branch info from the remote

Comment: Sounds like you have a permission issue. try what @slashpai suggested bellow and then attempt fetch again.

Answer (score 5):

I had a basic testing on this. The script: `git branch -r` is relying on remote reference of local git repository.

To get the remote branches, the best practice would be:

1. Firstly, execute the script: `git pull` / `git fetch` /... to sync latest remote repository data into your local repository;
2. Then execute the script: `git remote prune origin` to clean up those non-existed git branches in your local git repository;
3. Finally, execute the script: `git branch -r`

Answer (score 2):

do `git branch -a` it will give you all the branches in the remote.
another option `git fetch --all` Then if you want to change or what operation you want to give you can do.
example - if you want to change branch then `git checkout <branch name from shown branches>`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, but none of the answers helped me.

My problem was when i made the `git clone` i added the parameter `depth`.
This was my fault. So I cloned it again (without the depth parameter) and now i can see all branches.

Answer (score 0):

I am just updating,  when I faced this and how it solved , may be helpful for  someone in future.

I started repo using command `$git init` and later tried the command `$git branch` . But there was no output, later I added a new file and tried to commit. that time I got below error

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

After providing above details command `$git branch` worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar type of issue.

So, I first added one file for example index.php in staging area using `git add index.php` and after that did the `git commit -m some-text` then I tried `git branch` and it worked.

Hence, You need to make at least one commit before you can see the other branch listed by the `git branch` command.

Answer (score 0):

It will show some branches that fix your screen, use down button to scroll down, you will see other branches there.

Answer (score -4):

`git branch -M [branch-name]`

For instance:
`git branch -M master`

After this command, probably will should display:
* master

Comment: Hi, this answer is not very useful because: it doesn't answer the question and there has been an accepted answer for years which still works in today's version of git.

Comment: `git branch -M` is equivalent to `git branch --move --force`. Do not execute this unless you are a git expert. This answer should be deleted.