# Pycharm Merge Does Not Show All Branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm, git-merge

When I click branches at the right bottom corner I can see all the branches I need:

[image]

But when I open the Git -> Merge window:

[image]

I tried to Git -> Fetch but that does not solved my issue.

Why my branch showing up in the branches section but not in the merge section, what I am missing?

Comment: This really has little to do with Git; it's just a question about how to operate the PyCharm IDE. I'm not going to snip off the [tag:git] and [tag:git-merge] tags but I think they don't belong here. I think this is probably true of the [tag:intellij-idea] tag as well, although at least that's from the same company as PyCharm. :-)

Comment: Actually, I thought twice about adding git tags. I think this can be helpful to other people if they look for something like **IntelliJ git merge** or **Pycharm git merge**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git branch is not showing all the branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113509/git-branch-is-not-showing-all-the-branches)

Comment: No, my problem has been stated in the accepted answer. The problem was I tried to merge a `development` branch into `bugfix` branch but my `bugfix` branch already has the all commits from `development` branch.

Comment: `git branch --merged` is more relevant.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. A colleague had a similar issue with the master branch, and we could not explain why the master branch was not showing up in the dropdown "git merge". On his PC the master branch wasn't selectable on mine it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `bugfix/AAK-80732` already has all commits from development branch, this is why you cannot merge `development` into `bugfix` - there is simply nothing to merge into bugfix.

You can go to branches pane -> hold Ctrl/CMD and choose `bugfix/AAK-80732` and `development` branches and then press CMD/CTRL+D - this way you will get a comparison of two branches that will help you to understand.

Comment: Hold Ctrl does nothing in the branches section so I could not use Ctrl+D but when I click to the development branch while I'm in the bugfix branch there is a **Compare with Current** option showing up, I compared with this option. Accidentally I merged with the master branch which contains all things in the development plus more sophisticated things, because of that I could not see the development branch in the merge section. Your answer explains the matter. Can you provide documentation for shortcuts for the branches section?

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan perhaps we are talking about different "Branches" section.
I am talking about the one that is on a left side of a window (signed by number 1 in the link that I am sharing below), next to a Log, when you open Git toolwindow `Alt+9`. You can find it and more about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/log-tab.html?keymap=primary_windows

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to switch to the branch where you want to merge *AAK-80732*: *development*. After that, you can invoke *Git | Merge* and select *AAK-80732*.